# Excel function sometimes loads zero values to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have created excel  user defined formula via VBA that loads data from excel sheet to SQL server. I have used trigger in my sheet, that is verified by VBA Function before executing it. I do then connect to SQL server and use "insert into [table] ..." statement to load data from excel sheet to SQL Server. This works fine... almost always. Sometimes, however it loads zero value or zero values. I do not understand how it is possible and what can I do to avoid it. I will give simplified example of data. So it loads year, month, account number and value. VBA function reads  all those four elements from four separate excel cells and inserts to table. But I got once loaded right account, right amount, but zero for month... I definitelly have value between 1 and 12 in excel cells, so how come it loads zero? Could that be related to the way i force exporting to start? I used following code to set trigger to "yes" and then force calculation of formulas (this procedure is linked to button):

```
   Sub Export_LFVal()
    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "yes"
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    Application.Calculate
    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "No"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your INSERT code into the sql server?

Comment: yes, month is formatted as Integer in VBA function, numeric in SQL table. The actual SQL looks like this "insert into [Finance].[dbo].[FactForecast] (Year, Month, BusinessUnit,Ledger,Account,Amount,DateKey)  VALUES (2014,3,'Unit X','BU','P2310.03',100,'20140315')"

Comment: Have you stepped through in debug mode and verified that each attempted query properly loaded all the values into the insert statement?? On another note, I wonder if year and month being reserved words in SQL is giving you problems but I would've just expected the query to abort. Perhaps try putting either brackets or double quotes around those column names.

Comment: Good comment on Year and Month. I am still at early stage of developing this database, so I will rename it to FYear and FMonth, just to avoid possible problem in future. I am not sure I understand "that each attempted query properly loaded all the values into the insert statement" . I guess the fact that sometimes it loads zero, means that it does not properly load values. It is very hard to replicate that problem for me. Would be much easier if that would happen constantly.